# Codeigniter inserta caracteres raros

Tags: php, codeigniter

Llevo varias horas con el mismo problema y no se qué hacer. Codeigniter inserta ï¿½ después de hacer un echo o un var_dump. Siempre que imprimo algo por pantalla muestra el mismo caracter raro después. (No forma parte del string).

```
public function getRolesArr() {
    $sql = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM ROLES");
    $json = json_encode($sql->result_array());
    echo $json;
}
```

Uso este código en mi controller. y a continuación el output + caracteres raros. Tengo Codeigniter 3 con encoding UTF-8 por defecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puede que esté ocurriendo algo en la llamada a `$this->db->query` para depurar, comenta las dos líneas relativas a la BD y haz un `echo "cualquier cosa";` o crea u json a mano y haz un var_dump de él con json_encode.

Comment: En todos estos casos me ocurre lo mismo. He conseguido solucionarlo mandando los datos a un view. Creo que tenía que hacerlo así desde el principio.

Comment: Tal vez solo necesitas revisar si alguno de tus archivos está codificado en utf8 con BOM que, aunque parece algo sencillo, puede ser causante de muchos problemas como el que tenías.